# VS Code linting error in R scripts after installing new computer

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

After installing VS Code and R on my new work computer, the linting seems to have changed. Instead of the normal 4 spaces per indent, the linter insists on 2 spaces. As I have used 4 spaces in all of my scripts, there is a big pile-up of warnings clouding out all real warnings.

How can I change this particular linting setting (`indentation_linter`) back to its normal setting?

[image]